# Activities not being displayed on Approve Time Activities

Tags: acumatica

I am having trouble listing the Work Activity in Approve Time Activities Screen (EP507010). I created some 'Work Item' activities for a case.
[image]

I can see those activities in Employee Time Activities Screen (EP307000).

[image]

But, whenever I tried to load the case Work Item in Approve Time Activities Screen so that I (Owner of the case or Supervisor of Employee) can't see the Work Item.

[image]

I have tried several options such as:

1. Close the Case
2. Attach the Case to Project and Contract
3. Make sure the Case Class is set to Billable
4. Close the Work Item
   etc.

But none of these make it work.

PS: Though it's obvious, I have also made sure the features are set to Enable.

Thank you.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but are you sure they require approval?

Comment: Well no. Actually, I was the one who was asking this stupid question. You are right it doesn't need approval. I would be deleting this question.

Comment: Haha, we all have these days.